# unable to Write json to Pubsub topic using apache beam python

Tags: apache-beam

I am trying to read a topic from pubsub and do some cleanup/transfermation and write the final result to another pubsub topic. however i am ending up with the following error. pls guide me.

code:

```
Ingest = ( p
        | 'Read from Topic' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=known_args.topic).with_output_types(bytes)
        | 'Parse'   >> beam.Map(parse_json)
        | 'Cleanup' >> beam.Map(cleanup)
        | 'write to pubsub' | beam.io.WriteToPubSub("projects/test/topics/cdp_aa_food" , with_attributes=False)
       )
```

the error which i am getting is below:

```
raise TypeError("Expected a PTransform object, got %s" % transform)
TypeError: Expected a PTransform object, got write to pubsub
```

not sure what i am doing wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ingest = ( p
        | 'Read from Topic' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=known_args.topic).with_output_types(bytes)
        | 'Parse'   >> beam.Map(parse_json)
        | 'Cleanup' >> beam.Map(cleanup)
        | 'write to pubsub' >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub("projects/test/topics/cdp_aa_food" , with_attributes=False)
       )
```

There is a typo in your pipeline, you need `>>` instead of `|` for the `write to pubsub` step.